# Asp Core Static SPA Application , FallbackRoute not working

Tags: asp.net-core, single-page-application, asp.net-core-middleware, asp.net-core-1.1, asp.net-core-routing

**Given**

We have a  spa webpage in asp core.
Asp core just works as a static file handler .

To handle refresh scenarios we have a fallback which returns all requests to the template page.

Now locally and via docker container everything works fine.

**Problem**

When the site is hosted in IIS the fallback doesn't work.
When hitting F5 i got a 404 and the page not found site

In IIS Logs i can see that a 404 occurs but no redirect is called.

But locally when i debug in IISExpress everything works fine. Its only on the production IIS. So I assume some kind of default IIS mapping?

Here the code of the asp application

```
            app.UseResponseCompression();

            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            //Route Fallback middleware    
            app.Use(async (context, next) => 
            {
                await next();

                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/index.html"; 
                    await next();
                }
            });

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
```

I also tried but also not working

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();

                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/index.html");

                }
            });
```

Comment: Is anything written in the datastream at this point? You can only set headers (redirect is a header too) before any content is written. Also make sure you run the exact same environment on both (with the correct value for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable)

Comment: above is the whole asp code there is nothing more. all i'm triggering before ius a dotnet publish and currently manually copying the output to the iis folder

Comment: when running locally, is there a different with Kestrel or IIS express? did you also try Docker?